# Skip rows with a duplicate column value?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Say I'm returning a collection using `findAll()`, but a number of the rows have identical values in one column.

```
-----------------------------
| ID     name    placeId    |
-----------------------------
| 1      abc     123        |
| 2      def     123        | <- skip this (duplicate placeId)
| 3      ghi     456        |
| 4      jkl     789        |
| 5      mno     576        |
| 6      pqr     576        | <- skip this (duplicate placeId)
----------------------------
```

Is there a means in Sequelize to skip any rows (except the first) with duplicate column values?

Query's:

```
const items = await models.Item.findAll({
where: {
    [Op.and]: [
        sequelize.where(distance, { [Op.lte]: radius }),
        sequelize.where(descriptionFilter, { [Op.gte]: 2 }),
        {
            name: {
                [Op.notLike]: `%Example%`
            }
        }, {
            userId: {
                [Op.not]: me.id
            }
        },
    ]
},
order: distance,
limit: 25,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  It would be easiest to handle this using a raw Postgres query, so I suggest the following:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY placeId ORDER BY ID) rn2
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY placeId, rn1 - rn2
                                 ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM cte
)

SELECT ID, name, placeId
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID;
```

### Demo

Comment: You're absolutely right Tim - unfortunately the rest of the query is quite large and already written in Sequelize, so it's a bit of a last-resort to rewrite everything raw...

Comment: @MitchEff OK...I will leave this here as a valid solution, in case someone else would prefer to handle from a proc rather than from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**sequelize** supports aggregation function `min()`, so you can apply this on our code.

```
const items = await models.Item.findAll({
    attributes: [
        [sequelize.fn('MIN', sequelize.col('ID')), 'ID'],
    ],
    where: {
    [Op.and]: [
        sequelize.where(distance, { [Op.lte]: radius }),
        sequelize.where(descriptionFilter, { [Op.gte]: 2 }),
        {
            name: {
                [Op.notLike]: `%Example%`
            }
        }, {
            userId: {
                [Op.not]: me.id
            }
        },
        group: ['placeId'],
    ]
},
order: distance,
limit: 25,
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Ed! I moved `group: ['placeId']` outside the `where` clause as it was causing a syntax error, but then I get `column "item.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function]`... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql can do a job

```
select distinct on (placeid)
 * from example_table order by placeid,id
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7ab58b768a094b67b7060c799b4b4329)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best, but it solves the problem:

```
  SELECT T2.ID, T2.NAME, T2.PLACEID
  FROM
  (
    SELECT T1.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY placeId ORDER BY ID) RNK
    FROM test_tbl T1
  ) T2
  WHERE T2.RNK = 1
  ORDER BY T2.ID
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dJjy2aeq88X8MCQ1T6ucfw/0)